# Player em Javascript desaparece no celular

Tags: javascript

Olá,

Eu estou desenvolvendo um player em javascript quando executo no PC ele funciona normal, Mas quando estou no celular Android ele não funciona, Simplesmente desaparece, Agora quando tento no Windows Phone funciona normalmente:

```
function playSong(song, id) {

    // Remove the current-song class (if any)
    $('.current-song').removeClass('current-song');
    // Show the previously hidden Play button (if any)
    $('.current-play').show();
    $('.current-play').removeClass('current-play');

    // Remove the active player if exist and set the ghost player
    $('.current-seek').html($('#sound_ghost_player').html());

    // Remove the active player class
    $('.current-seek').removeClass('current-seek');

    // Escape the ID (contains dots) http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/
    var parsedId = song.replace('.', '\\.');

    // Add the current song class
    $('#track'+id).addClass('current-song');
    // Add current play class to the Play button and hide it
    $('#play'+id).addClass('current-play');
    $('.current-play').hide();

    // Get the current played song name
    if ($('#song-name'+id).html().length > 25) {
        var songName = $('#song-name'+id).html().substr(0, 25)+'...';
    } else {
        var songName = $('#song-name'+id).html();
    }

    $('#sw-song-name').html(songName);

    // Show the time holder when a song starts playing
    $('.jp-audio .jp-time-holder').show();

    // Destroy the player if any is active
    $("#sound-player").jPlayer("destroy");

    // Add the active player to the current song
    $("#song-controls"+id).html($("#seek-bar-song").html());

    // Add the active player class to the current song
    $("#song-controls"+id).addClass('current-seek');

    // Set the play/pause button position (this is needed for mobile view in order for the play/pause button to be at the same height with the initial play button)
    $('#track'+id+' .jp-play , #track'+id+' .jp-pause').css({ 'margin-top' : '-' + $('.song-top', '#track'+id).outerHeight() + 'px' });

    // Get the track extension
    var ext = getExtension(song);

    // Determine prev next buttons
    prevnext();
    $("#sound-player").jPlayer({
        ready: function (event) {
            if(ext == 'mp3') {
                $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                    mp3: '{$url}/uploads/tracks/'+song
                }).jPlayer("play");
            } else if(ext == 'm4a') {
                $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                    m4a: '{$url}/uploads/tracks/'+song              
                }).jPlayer("play");
            }
        },
        cssSelectorAncestor: '#sound-container',
        ended: function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "{$url}/requests/add_view.php",
                data: "id="+id, 
                cache: false,
                success: function(html) {

                }
            });

            // If repeat is not turned on, move to the next song
            if($('#repeat-song').html() == 0) {
                $('.current-seek').html($('#sound_ghost_player').html());
                $('.current-play').show();
                nextSong(id);
            }
        },
        error: function() {
            // If the track fails to play for whatever reasons, hide it
            $('#track'+id).fadeOut();
            nextSong(id);
        },
        errorAlerts: true,
        swfPath: "{$url}/{$theme_url}/js",
        supplied: ext,
        wmode: "window",
        volume: getCookie("volume"),
        smoothPlayBar: true,
        solution: "html, flash",
        keyEnabled: true
    });
};
</script>
```

Comment: Manda o link do site.

Comment: http://mulsica.com.br/index.php?a=track&id=56

Comment: Qual o aparelho e a versão do android que você está testando?

Answer (score 2):

**Chrome Android**:

- O player do topo não funciona
- As listas de player, no corpo do site, estão sumindo ao serem clicadas no player.

**Navegador Nativo Android**:

- O player do topo **funciona**
- As listas de player, no corpo do site, estão sumindo ao serem clicadas no player.

*Resumindo, o seu problema é de compatibilidade. Veja está tabela:*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Há alguns bugs, que não foram resolvidos, para dispositivos móveis no seu JavaScript:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

*Resumindo aconselho a você rever e testar sua API e migrar para outras versões e sair testando. Veja essa linha de estudo:*

### http://pupunzi.open-lab.com/2013/03/13/making-html5-audio-actually-work-on-mobile/

### https://github.com/pupunzi/jquery.mb.audio/blob/master/demo.html

### http://codetheory.in/fixing-html5-audio-problems-in-ios-and-android-mobile-browsers-to-overcome-the-limitations/

http://www.createjs.com/Demos/SoundJS/TestSuite